# Can't get data of a problematic section with Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'd like to get the contents of the "Goalscorers" section from the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup#Goalscorers.
I used the command

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=2014_FIFA_World_Cup&rvprop=content&rvsection=32
```

but I get an empty section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <normalized>
      <n from="2014_FIFA_World_Cup" to="2014 FIFA World Cup" />
    </normalized>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="656933" ns="0" title="2014 FIFA World Cup">
        <revisions>
          <rev contentformat="text/x-wiki" contentmodel="wikitext" xml:space="preserve">===Goalscorers===
{{2014 FIFA World Cup Goalscorers}}</rev>
        </revisions>
      </page>
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

How can I get the actual data of this section with the Wikipedia API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an empty section, it's a section that contains the `2014 FIFA World Cup Goalscorers` template. You need to get this template's content: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Template:2014%20FIFA%20World%20Cup%20Goalscorers&rvprop=content
But oh shi~~, it's a [redirect](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aRedirects) to another template called `2014 FIFA World Cup goalscorers` (note the difference!), so you need to get its content too: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Template:2014%20FIFA%20World%20Cup%20goalscorers&rvprop=content

Comment: Or you could bypass the redirect by adding `&redirects` to the first query.